# Json marshalling in dart

Tags: json, dart, marshalling

I have i small question about json serializing in dart. I am using "exportable" lib.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/exportable

Here a small code:

```
Condition t = new Condition();
Configurator configurator1 = new Exportable(Configurator);
configurator1.alias = conf_b_1;
configurator1.value = conf1;

Configurator configurator2 = new Exportable(Configurator);
configurator2.alias = conf_b_2;
configurator2.value = conf2;

t.configurators.add(configurator1);
ntp.condition = t;

print("________________toString_______________");
print(""+t.toString());
print("_______________________________________");
print("________________toJson_______________");
print(""+t.toJson());
print("_______________________________________");
```

and the result is:

________________toString_______________
{"ref":"4","logicalRefId":"41","value":"1","alias":false,"configurators":["{\"alias\":\"1\",\"value\":\"10\"}"]}

---

________________toJson_______________
{"ref":"4","logicalRefId":"41","value":"1","alias":false,"configurators":["{\"alias\":\"1\",\"value\":\"10\"}"]}

The configurator part is totally broken. Where am i doing it wrong ?

Thx in advance for reading me,
Nerio.

Comment: I've never used exportable, but it seems to be outputting string for int values as well. :( [based on your question]

Comment: Yes. It's true. Do you have a better approach ?

Comment: i usually serialize/deserialize by implementing toJson()/fromJson() and do the job manually. I know however that many people started projects to do this lately.